# Backbone $el is not synced with dom

Tags: jquery, dom, backbone.js, view

View is bind to its self change event (it's an input). After re-render $el keeps reacting to this event, but $el.val() returns previous value. But when I in debug mode search for this element by $(...).val() it returns valid value.

I thought it somehow unbinded from dom, but when I rerender again and vie sets $el.val(...) it's set well.

How could this happen?

P.S. view is removed and appended on re-renedr and delegateevents is called in render method

Comment: Consider reproducing the problem or posting the related code!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in adding subviews not with this.$el.append but with this.$el.after